# API with secret hash

Tags: php, hash

I'm creating a APi on my server to reset passwords for users.

I want to make it secure, so that someone could not simply POST the data to the php script and it would reset someone elses password.  So in order to do this, i've created a hash with `sha256`.  The hash has two salts, and looks similar to this:

`hash("sha256","salt1".date("jS M Y H")."salt2")`

So, in order to validate it I hash it on the page and take the last 32 characters, and in the API scripts I have the first 32 characters.  I join them together to validate, and if it matches the full hash, it allows the script to execute.

This works fine, expect if the user happens to load the public page at 59 minutes past the hour, and submit it after the hour changes.  Same goes for month, and year.

I dont want to simply set a static hash, I want it to change.  Is there a better method or way I could achieve the results I want?

Comment: Please go back to the first paragraph… what problem *exactly* are you trying to prevent here?

Comment: @deceze If I had no hash validation, anyone could look at the javascript that is submitting the data and find the php file URL, and post the correct data to it to change someone elses password.

Answer (score 0):

You're steering in the wrong direction to solve the underlying problem here. Use tried and true methods:

1. If the user wants to *change* their password while they're already logged in, obviously the server knows who the user is – because they're logged in – and will only ever change the password of the current user.
2. For a *forgot-password* system, you need an out-of-band mechanism to confirm the user's identity, meaning you typically send them an email which contains information the user must provide when they attempt to reset their password. This typically means you generate a long random token (simple random bytes converted to hex or base 64 or something else that's transmittable via plaintext), store that in the database, send it in the email (e.g. as link `reset.php?token=...`), and when the user enters their new password and submits the form, they're sending the new password *and the token* to your server. The server now looks up that token, which should be unique in your database, and thus knows what user is trying to change their password.

   The security here comes from the assumption that the token is too long and random to be guessable, and that only the intended user will ever see the token (which means we assume email is a secure enough channel to transmit it). You also let the token expire after a reasonable amount of time (say, a few hours) or after it has been used once.

   There's no need to involve any additional hashes here.

Comment: As an additional security for the first point, many systems will prompt the user to enter the old password on password change. The system will match old password to the logged-in user, and only change password if that validation is correct.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I do do that, the user is sent an email with example.com/login/reset-password/345345345jj4k5kl (hash).  So you're saying thats enough?

Comment: @Jan Yes, that is to prevent somebody from locking you out of your account if you leave your computer unattended for a few minutes. I didn't want to mix that secondary issue into this one…

Comment: @JanSverre my problem is that nearlyall my users have no idea what their password is in the first place, so If I did that i'd be answering lots of password reset emails.

Comment: @Chud37 Yes, that's enough. If anyone can hook into that chain of communication to get the hash value, the entire thing is already compromised anyway. Note though: what "hash" are you sending? You shouldn't send anything that can be derived from something else, you should send an entirely random meaningless token.